# Style a block with separate backgrounds on the block itself and the text within it

Tags: html, css

The effect I am after is to have different backgrounds on a block and the text within the block, like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: indigo;
}
p {
  background-color: orange;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  background-color: moccasin;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Highlight this text</span></p>
```

Is there a way of doing this without the `<span>` element? So with just CSS and the following HTML markup?

```
<p>Highlight this text</p>
```

I was looking at the available list of pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements, but can't see anything which might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and without pseudo element

```css
body {
  background-color: indigo;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  display:table; /* fit text content*/
  margin:auto; /* center */
  background-color: moccasin; /* main background */
  box-shadow:0 0 0 200vmax orange; /* a huge shadow to simulate the second background */
  clip-path:inset(0 -100vmax); /* clip the shadow to show only left/right part of it */
}
```

```html
<p>Highlight this text</p>
```